# Even parity applied on bits, that don't follow the rules of even parity

Tags: error-correcting-codes

The following example is given:

> The sender and receiver are using 1 bit even parity
> The sender is sending 1110 1010 over a noisy channel.
>
> in case 1 the receiver gets 1110 1100
>
> in case 2 the receiver gets 1110 1001
>
> Which one of this two cases was detected and why wasn't the other one ?

I don't understand how one error can be detected and the other error can't. Both have the exact same number of o's and 1's. Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Are you sure `1110 1010` is correct? It does not have even parity.

Comment: Yes i double checked.This is the reason i'm asking. I also don't understand how this should work. So i posted it here,because it was an exercise i found online. I wanted to make sure i'm not missing something here.

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. usually odd number of 1's means odd parity.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please [tell who originated the example presented and where you encountered it](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).